# Can't start android app on device

Tags: android

I can start my android app in android simulator and it works fine for all resolutions and from android 2.1.

But I want to test the app on real device, too. So I copied the apk file from the bin folder of my app to the sd card of my device and installed the app successfully.

My device is a HTC HD2 with an android mod. The app starts but shows just a black screen.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: why dont you try directly installing the app in your device.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: Plug your device into your PC and use the DDMS perspective of eclipse to trace what's happening. I don't do 'mind reading' on Fridays so, no, I have no idea what might be wrong.

Comment: you should try to install your app via adb and then debug the app. Without any further information it is highly unlikely to get your question answered here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the logcat information from the device, too. Just connect it and start `adb logcat` or select the device in eclipse.

You can also install your app on the device using eclipse. Connect it and see if it shows up in the device view. If not, try to restart `adb` by using `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.

Debugging works the same way.

Unfortunately a blank screen doesn't provide enough information to help you. I guess you need to dig deep into the app, add some `log.d` calls to see until where it loads.